# Polymer Custom Animations

Tags: polymer

I've got a question regarding animations with polymer. I want to make a custom element in polymer and have some default animations on it. In the past I would have used jQuery, but I would like to test the possibilities of the Material Design Library.

I have an element containing a date, whenever I click on it, it should transform and show details.

Here is a link to the animation I would like to get. 
https://vid.me/yyFN
I'm sorry for the watermark, it was the first thing I fount to capture the screen.

What would be the best way to get this animation in a custom element on the Polymer Library?

Bart

Ps: This is my first question, please help me if this question is incorrect or not the way it should.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwvi1u4XXzc) great video produced by Google that talks about animation with Polymer. There is already and element called `neon-animation` (docs [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation)) that contains lots of useful animations for you to use. This video will also show you how you can write your own animations and use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an element for that! it is called neon-animation, you can find it in the Polymer's Catalog :
[neon-animations](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation)
neon animations provide pre-defined animations you can use in your web app, but first you need to understand the concept of web animation in the Polymer world.
There is no better tutorial than these three videos on animations done by Rob Dodson:

1. [Behaviours](https://youtu.be/YrlmieL3Z0k?list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN)
2. [Slick Web Animations](https://youtu.be/Lwvi1u4XXzc?list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN)
3. [neon-Animated Pages](https://youtu.be/wMhq1o0DULM?list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN)

Its recommended, no its vital you watch them in order

Comment: Thank you very much, I will watch them!

Comment: I can't upvote, since my reputation is not good enough. I accepted the answer though.